# How to make iOS notification stay on screen longer, similar to Hangouts or Facebook Messanger?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm working on an app that has a feature to make phone or video calls.  When you do this with Hangouts or Facebook Messanger app, there is a push notification that gets sent to the recipient.  However this notification is a little different in 2 aspects.

1. It plays a ringing sound in a loop (whether it's just 1 long sound clip vs. a short one in loop, I am not technically sure).
2. The notification stays on the recipients screen the entire duration of the initiator making the call, until they either hang up or the recipient taps on it.

I have been searching google and I am unable to find any information on how this is done.  Does anyone know how Google or Facebook has implemented this type of notification feature?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some further google searching, I did come across the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18383035/5390680

It appears that it does in fact stay longer if you have a longer sound, up to 30 seconds, so I will just create a looping sound.